# how to merge all the notebooks of zeppelin into one?

Tags: mysql, apache-zeppelin, bigdata

I have notebook1 and notebook2 of zeppelin , one is from mongodb and the other one is from sql.

How to merge these 2 notebooks, pls help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible using the WebInterface.

However you can do this by using the Notebook source. You can find them at `$ZEPPELIN_HOME/notebooks` followed by the ID of your notebook you can find in your Browser url. Notebooks are stored in JSON-Syntax and the content can be found unter paragraphs. So just copy all children of the paragraphs tag of one notebook into the paragraphs tag of the other notebook

Comment: Hi, I'll try this  and let you know. If possible, pls let me know any other alternative way?